# How does a kafka connect connector know which schema to use?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

Let's say I have a bunch of different topics, each with their own json schema. In schema registry, I indicated which schemas exist within the different topics, not directly refering to which topic a schema applies. Then, in my sink connector, I only refer to the endpoint (URL) of the schema registry. So to my knowledge, I never indicated which registered schema a kafka connector (e.g., JDBC sink) should be used in order to deserialize a message from a certain topic?

Asking here as I can't seem to find anything online.

I am trying to decrease my kafka message size by removing overhead of having to specify the schema in each message, and using schema registry instead. However, I cannot seem to understand how this could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your producer serializes the schema id directly in the bytes of the record. Connect (or consumers with the json deserializer) use the schema that's part of each record.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

If you're trying to decrease message size, don't use JSON, but rather a binary format and enable topic compression such as ZSTD